# Using <ol class> to produce letters and numbers on the same line

Tags: c#, html, css, html-lists, blazor

Is there a way to use the ol class to produce an output, like the following in a quiz format.

1. A Hello
2. B Goodbye
3. C See You
4. D Great

I can output one or the other, but not together. I understand you can't use
two ol classes...

```
<style>
    ol.o {
        list-style-type: upper-alpha;
    }
    li {
        list-style-type: decimal;
    }
</style>

 <ol class="o">
                  
                        <li>@QuizItem.Option1</li>
                        <li>@QuizItem.Option2</li>
                        <li>@QuizItem.Option3</li>
                        @if (QuizItem.Option4 != null)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option4</li>
                        }
                        @if (QuizItem.Option5 != null)
                        {
                            <li>@QuizItem.Option5</li>
                        }
                  
                    </ol>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS-Counters

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: listStyle;
}

ol li {
  margin-left: 1em;
  counter-increment: listStyle;
}

ol li::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  content: counter(listStyle, upper-alpha);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
</ol>
```